# Cannot access items array property of MapView.allLayerViews - ArcJS API 4.4

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

See below:

```
require(["esri/Map","esri/views/MapView"], function(Map, MapView) {
    var map = new Map({ basemap: "streets" });

    var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-97.744483, 30.272705],
        zoom: 15,
    });

console.log(view.allLayerViews.items);
```

[image]

```
console.log(view.allLayerViews.items[0]);
```

[image]

```
console.log(view.allLayerViews.length);
```

[image]

I suppose the array calls are accessing the Array prototype, but I don't know how to make it not do that. I would like to be able to loop through the layerViews with `forEach()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access the `allLayerViews` collection immediately after instantiating the MapView, the layers didn't have a chance to load yet.

You could set up a [watch](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/working-with-props/index.html#watchProperties) on the collection's length property which will execute when the length changes from 0 to 1.

```
view.watch('allLayerViews.length', function () {
    console.log(view.allLayerViews.length); //outputs 1
});
```

Comment: An answer on GeoNet also suggested I embed `lyr.then()` inside of `view.then()`